# Generating JavaFX project with Maven

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, javafx

I'm trying to create new JavaFX Maven Project in IntelliJ Idea  using the following pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>pl.edu.pg.eti.pcej</groupId>
    <artifactId>pl.edu.pg.eti.pcej.wi.clustermap</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>


</project>
```

I cannot generate project, because I've got the following warnings and errors:

```
[WARNING] Property organizationName is missing. Add -DorganizationName=someValue
```

...

```
    [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:2.2:generate (default-cli) on project standalone-pom: Archetype com.zenjava:javafx-basic-archetype:2.0.1 is not configured
    [ERROR] Property organizationName is missing.
    [ERROR] -> [Help 1]
    [ERROR] 
    [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
    [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
    [ERROR] 
    [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
    [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
    [ERROR] Maven execution terminated abnormally (exit code 1)
```

How can I fix it in IntelliJ?

EDIT:

I'm creating new project from archetype com.zenjava:javafx-basic-archetype // javafx-basic-arcehtype:2.0.1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In project creation wizard, there is a window with "Maven home directory" input field at the top. On this window you can see a table with parameters for template. Add `organizationName` parameter there.